# GTK+ compiling problem

Tags: compiling, gtk

When I try to compile [GTimer 2.00](http://kaz.dl.sourceforge.net/project/gtimer/2.0.0/gtimer-2.0.0.tar.gz)
 I get the following error:

```
$ ./configure

checking for GTK+ - version >= 2.4.0... no
*** Could not run GTK+ test program, checking why...
*** The test program failed to compile or link. See the file config.log for the
*** exact error that occured. This usually means GTK+ is incorrectly installed.
configure: error: No GTK found. Set the path right or install it.
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you don't have the building dependencies to build the package. Please run:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep gtimer
```

You must be sure that you have the `deb-src` repositories in your `sources.list`.

On other hand, the package is already included in the repositories of Ubuntu, please consider installing those instead building yourself.

Comment: How can I add deb-src to the sources?

Comment: @MinimusHeximus Tick the Source code in your Software Source as [show here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Ubuntu_Software_Tab)

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following command:

```
./configure --with-gtk2
```

It really works.